# Best way to change incremental ID to account for deleted rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering if there was a good way to change the incremental ID of all rows to account for deleted ones, a 1 time thing sort of thing.

For example, if you had 400 rows and you deleted 200, the 400th row would still have the ID 400 - how would you make it so it matches the row number with a query?

This would shift every number after the first deleted rows.

Reason why I would want to do this is because the IDs increase and gets deleted very fast, which means that the incremental ID gets very high very fast. But there's a ton of empty gaps which I would like to reduce the numbers so its easier to work with.

Comment: You should normally not have to worry about this, assuming you don't expect to be turning over billions of records at a fast go.  If you want some kind of ordered sequence, then look into using things like `ROW_NUMBER` and `RANK`, against an appropriate column which provides an ordering you want.

Comment: There is no need to do that. The **only** job of a generated primary key is to be unique, it's actual value is completely meaningles. Gaps in the numbering are no problem and there is nothing to fix. Even if you constantly burn 10000 values per second without pause, it will take 29247120 years to exhaust the (bigint) sequence (if you accept negative values twice that time)